# Getting 'SurefireExecutionException' while running TestNG project via maven test

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a main class that I want to run via maven, this main class dynamically creates testng.xml file and that's how the testing starts. But when I run my project via 'Run as->maven test' I get 'SurefireExecutionException' . Below is the pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
          <configuration>
          <forkMode>never</forkMode>
          <parallel>tests</parallel>
          <threadCount>10</threadCount>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>java</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>main.MainRunner</mainClass>
    <arguments>
    </arguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>2.41.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

and this is the stacktrace:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.683 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-20T19:07:20+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) on project Automata: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to D:\Git\automata\Automata\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] Exception in provider
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireExecutionException: Exception in provider
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:91)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1166)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/ITestContext
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.tryGetMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:60)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isSuiteOnly(JUnit3TestChecker.java:66)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isValidJUnit3Test(JUnit3TestChecker.java:61)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.accept(JUnit3TestChecker.java:56)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.PojoAndJUnit3Checker.accept(PojoAndJUnit3Checker.java:44)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultScanResult.applyFilter(DefaultScanResult.java:102)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.scanClassPath(JUnit3Provider.java:147)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.invoke(JUnit3Provider.java:91)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:206)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:161)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:84)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:87)
[ERROR]     ... 25 more
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.ITestContext
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.IsolatedClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedClassLoader.java:100)
[ERROR]     ... 46 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Edit: Like suggested by Krishnan below, I added the testng dependency in my pom.xml file, after doing that it looks like BeforeSuite and BeforeTest classes are working, but the actual tests aren't working, this is what I get now:

```
Surefire suite started.....
In Before Test
Starting ChromeDriver 2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90) on port 25689
Only local connections are allowed.
[1545327410.041][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
Dec 20, 2018 11:06:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
new instance
Surefire suite ended.....
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 31.895 s - in TestSuite
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 35.638 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-20T23:06:58+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would really appreciate if some light is thrown on this.

Edit: Opened up a new question for the above query here: 
[Unable to run testNG tests from maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53874321/unable-to-run-testng-tests-from-maven)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.ITestContext` suggests that you are missing testng library from your classpath.

Please add a dependency on testng to your pom file and try again. You should be fine. (something like below)

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0-beta1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes I thought of it and added the testng dependency in the pom.xml file later and it looked fine initially, but it looks like only my BeforeSuite and BeforeTest classes are working, the actual tests aren't working, you see I  am running my project from the main function and trying to get it work via maven as well but I keep getting these issues.

Comment: I have edited my question with the latest output after I added testng dependency in my pom.xml

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show us what your `main.MainRunner` looks like ? I am guessing that you are using the testng apis. If that's the case, can you please bump the verbosity via `testng.setVerbose(3)`, run your test again and update what you see? That should basically show you whats going on. Btw, I think your original question has been answered since the exception goes away. You should perhaps create a new question for that. Please dont forget to accept my answer

Comment: Hello Krishnan, I have asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53874321/unable-to-run-testng-tests-from-maven    perhaps you can take a look at it.